# Getting activity Id in postmonger onRequestedInteraction event

Tags: journeybuilder, custom-activity

I am looking for possibility to get an **id** of next activity following my custom activity.

My idea was to use postmonger **requestInteraction** event, where I was able to get current journey JSON object with all activities, and using **outcomes** and **next** activity key.

Only problem is, that in response on the **requestInteraction** event, activity ID is not returned ;-(

So I am able to get activity Key but not Activity Id.

```
*** requestedInteraction *** : 
{
"id":"9211dcee-3156-4549-a427-6271ecd60f58",
"version":1,
"useDefinitionId":false,
"name":"New Journey - 12 July 2023 at 12.29",
"description":"",
"workflowApiVersion":1,
"entryMode":"NotSet",
"activities":[
   {
     "key":"REST-1",
     "name":"",
     "description":"",
     "type":"REST",
     "outcomes":[
        {
         "key":"ae53b6f3-d254-4a34-aba1-60230d14f6f4",
         "next":"REST-2",
         "arguments":{},
         "metaData":{"invalid":false}
        }
     ],

  ...
 },
 {
  "key":"REST-2",
  "name":"XYZ",
  "description":"",
  "type":"REST",
  "outcomes":[
     {
     "key":"7bf386f6-8309-4576-ae55-3a23490176ef",
     "next":"WAITBYDURATION-1",
     ...
     }
  ]
 }
]
...
```

Using REST API, *GET /interaction/v1/interactions/{id}*, I am able to get activities of a current journey but need to perform additional API call.

```
    "activities": [
        {
            "id": "11b1b111-9988-e111-9ef0-88aaa9dddbb1",
            "key": "send-welcome-email",
            "name": "Welcome email",
...
```

Is there any way to tell onRequestInteraction postmonger event to return activityId as well?